# How can I fix, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Aim of this is to try get a local image saved on your computer sent to a discord channel via a bot

```
# Create an Intents object with the `messages` attribute set to True
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)

# Create the client with the specified intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # When the bot is ready, send the image to the specified channel
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    with open(r"file path", 'rb') as f:
        file = discord.File(f)
        await channel.send(file=file)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path", line 39, in on_ready
    await channel.send(file=file)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: `channel` seems to be `none`, in other words `get_channel()` is not finding anything. You may want to look into the docs to see what may be causing it.
I looked at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) for you, and it says that it is most likely that `CHANNEL_ID` is not an actual in-use ID

Answer (score 0):

[The offical documentation for Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) says

> **Parameters:**
> id ([int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)) – The ID to search for.
>
> **Returns:**
> The returned channel or `None` if not found.

This means that the ID supplied does not match any server, so most likely you mistyped it or accidentally modified it in code somewhere

Comment: i checked on discord using the <#(channel id)> function to check if it was correct which it was, then went back to my code and changed it to an integer before i passed it through just in case that was the issue, but still got the same error

Comment: So how does the definition of CHANNEL_ID look?

Comment: CHANNEL_ID = int(1056240677471653950)

Comment: that `int()` is indeed not necessary, but won't hurt either. Are you sure that the bot can reach the chanel?

Comment: yes because i also have functions where it responds to the user based on the given input, like if the user says 'hello' it replies in the channel (same channel id as the one in this post) 'Hello There!'

Answer (score 0):

```
    await channel.send(file=file)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

So `channel` is `None`, so the error was caused by the following.

---

```
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
```

I guess 99% that `CHANNEL_ID` is a `str`ing and not an `int`eger...

Comment: CHANNEL_ID = int(1056240677471653950)

Comment: So the bot actually **is** in the guild where the channel is?

Comment: yes it is has every permission too